# is it possible to find row count of a table using data reader?

Tags: asp.net

is it possible to find row count of a table using data reader?

Answer (score 2):

If you need the count of sth write a different query such as `select count(*) from ??` and execute the `ExecuteScalar()` on it instead of `ExecuteReader()`

Comment: or you could add the rowcount as a extra column on the result-set and access it through the reader

Answer (score 2):

No direct property that you could use. You should be able to iterate through it and count rows:

```
Int32 rowCount = 0;
while (reader.Read()) rowCount++;
```

I would not recommend it though. Its a waste for something a single query with a single result could do.

Answer (score 0):

DataReader normally fetches the row upon calling .Read() method. It doesn't have any information on the number of rows in the underlying result set until it reaches the last row.